# Ограничение возможностей у браузера через модуль webbrowser (python)

Tags: python, веб-программирование, webbrowser

вопрос следующий : возможно ли ограничить возможности браузера (нажатие кнопок, ввод собственного url), используя метод webbrowser?

Мне нужно, чтобы окно браузера открывалось и я мог находиться только на одном сайте, не мог бы заходить в настройки браузера, изменять url адрес.

```
import webbrowser as wb

window = wb.open(urlSite, 0, True)
```

Comment: Для этого нужно запускать браузер в режиме киоска, и модуль webbrowser для такого не предназначен

Comment: какой модуль для этих целей может подойти?

Comment: subprocess например